# Some questions about the derivation process of many-body Green's functions (specifically, the Hedin equations)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, functional-derivatives, density-functional-theory

The response of the Green's function under the action of an external field can be represented by the density correlation function L:

$$L_{s_1 s'_{1} , s_2 s_{2'} }(12) = - i \hbar \frac{ \delta G_{s_1 s'_1}(11^{+})}{ \delta \phi_{s_2 , s'_2} (2)} \Big{|}_{ \phi = 0 }$$

The general derivation method is to peel off the external field term of the Hamiltonian and place it in the evolution factor $S = \hat{T} exp ( \frac{1}{i \hbar} \int \mathrm{d} t H_{ \mathrm{ext}} (t) )$($\hat{T}$ is time order operator), and derive the following result:

$$ \frac{ \delta G_{s_1 s'_1} (11')}{ \delta \phi_{s_2 s'_2} (2^+) } = G_{s_1 s'_1} (11') G_{s_2 s'_2} (22') - G_{s_1 s_2 , s'_1 s'_2 } (12,1'2') $$

However, if we consider the case where there is no electron-electron interaction, that is, the electrons are independent of each other, L can be obtained directly by functional differentiation of the single particle Green function

$$L^{0}_{s_1 s'_1, s_2 s'_2} (11',22') = -i \hbar G_{s_1 s'_2} (12') G_{s_2 s'_1} ( 21' )$$

You can see that the two-particle Green's function has disappeared. My question is, how do these two transition? It seems that the second formula cannot directly obtain $L^{0}$.

I truly appreciate any insights or guidance that you could provide on this matter. Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve figured it out. All I need to do is apply Wick’s theorem to contract this two-particle Green’s function. I’m sorry for wasting everyone’s time.